# HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Duration. Did you forget to register an adapter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

after I added this Duration field in this model

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
part 'workout_record.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 3)
class WorkOutRecordModel {
  @HiveField(1)
  final String icon;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String workoutName;
  @HiveField(3)
  final DateTime dateTime;
  @HiveField(5)
  final Duration duration;

  WorkOutRecordModel({
    required this.dateTime,
    required this.icon,
    required this.workoutName,
   required this.duration,
  });
}
```

I'm getting this error *Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Duration. Did you forget to register an adapter?
*

i deleted the workout_record.g.dart and recreated after I added the duration field. I already registered the adapter so wondering what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [`TypeAdapter`](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/type_adapters) for that.

This uses the milliseconds of a duration to store it:

```dart
class DurationAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Duration> {
  @override
  final typeId = 0; // Put an ID you didn't use yet.

  @override
  Duration read(BinaryReader reader) {
    return Duration(milliseconds: reader.readInt());
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Duration obj) {
    writer.writeInt(obj.inMilliseconds);
  }
}
```

And don't forget to register it

```dart
void main() {
  Hive
    ..registerAdapter(WorkOutRecordModelAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter(DurationAdapter()); // <- Register your duration adapter.
}
```

Comment: so I have to create another adapter for Duration. Thanks for answering